# Digitally signing an executable to prevent blocking by Symantec Endpoint

Tags: security, symantec

I recently installed [`context`](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Installation) on a laptop for which I do not control the security policy. The laptop has symantec endpoint protection installed and when I try to run the `context` executable from the command line Symantec Endpoint Protection opens with this window:

[image]

As it turns out, I can simply allow the file and the executable works as expected. I would like to sign this program such that symantec does not pick it up as a security risk. I installed the Windows Software Development Kit with `signtool` and tried the following command:

`signtool sign /fd C:\context\tex\texmf-win64\bin\context.exe`

Unfortunately, I got an error:

> SignTool Error: The specified algorithm cannot be used or is invalid.

How can I sign the file without `signtool` throwing such an error? I've seen some stuff about `certreq` but I'm not sure if that's the way to go....

Comment: Not sure if this question belongs here or in [superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Ok I have moved it : https://superuser.com/questions/1685739/digitally-signing-an-executable-to-prevent-blocking-by-symantec-endpoint